# Linux на mac

Tags: mac, linux

Как установить Linux на компьютер Apple в качестве второй операционной системы?

Comment: Вопрос для знающих. Grub может определить MacOS ?

Answer (score 1):

- [Установка Linux на MacBook](http://www.linuks.lt/index.php?page=mac)
- [Подробнее про установку Линукс рядом с Виндовс (с картинками)](http://myubuntu.ru/rukovodstvo/ustanovka-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

1. Установить бутлодер, поддерживающий Linux, например http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/
2. Установить дистр, поддерживающий UEFI, например свежую Убунту

Answer (score 0):

Взять дистрибутив "заточенный" под мак... И установить! Например, [Yellow Dog](http://www.yellowdoglinux.com/). Или любой другой, имеющий установочные образы для архитектуры РРС.

Comment: По-моему даже в древнем 2012 PPC-маки оставались в основном в музеях :)